# What is <template> in angular2 and its use?

Tags: angular

On the [line 91 of this angular2 control](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/tabset/tabset.ts), a special tag `<template>` is used. What is its use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on the angular [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#template):

> Structural directives, like ngIf, do their magic by using the **HTML 5 template tag.**

What are **structural directives**?

> A Structural directive changes the DOM layout by adding and removing
>   DOM elements. We've seen three of the built-in structural directives
>   in other chapters: ngIf, ngSwitch and ngFor.

What is the **HTML 5 template element**? Take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template).

> The HTML  element is a mechanism for holding client-side content that is not to be rendered when a page is loaded but may subsequently be instantiated during runtime using JavaScript.

**Example**:

```
<p *ngIf="test.length > 0"><h1>Hello</h1></p>
```

the asterix * shows that it is a structural directive. 
The non-shorthand syntax for the example above is:

```
<template [ngIf]=”test.length > 0">
    <p>
       <h1>Hello</h1>
    </p>
</template>
```

So if the result of the expression is false, the element will be removed from the DOM.

Comment: This <template> tags change the ShadowDom, not the DOM directly. They generate custom HTML on the LightDom or Visible Browser Dom as you call It with <script> tags

Comment: The `<template>` tag is not related to Shadow DOM. It's just a container for partial views that can be stamped to the DOM by directives like `NgFor`, `NgIf`, `createEmbeddedView`, `ngTemplateOutlet`, ...